# How can i improve Animation Code?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 2 buttons in screen; moveLeft and moveRight. When I press the left or right button, walk function is working. But sprite seems like sliding. How can I improve this?

Sprite names like this; 
player_walk_left_000, player_walk_left_001 ... 009
player_walk_right_000, player_right_left_02 ... 009

```
tapBegin(on button: String) {

        if button == "left" {
            walk(imagedNamed: "player_walk_left_00", direction: "left")
        } else if button == "right"{
           walk(imagedNamed: "player_walk_right_00", direction: "right")
        } else {
            //jump() I will develop here
        }
    }

tapEnd(on button:String) {
        if button == "left" {
            player.removeAction(forKey: "moveLeft")
        } else if button == "right" {
            player.removeAction(forKey: "moveRight")
        }
    }

func walk(imagedNamed: String, direction: String) {
    let playerWalk: SKAction
    var textures:[SKTexture] = []
    for i in 0...9 {
        textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(imagedNamed)\(i)"))
    }
    textures.append(textures[2])
    textures.append(textures[1])
    if direction == "left" {
        playerWalk = SKAction.animate(with: textures,timePerFrame: 0.1)
        let leftForever = SKAction.repeatForever(playerWalk)
        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -60, y: 0, duration: 0.2)
        let moveLeftForEver = SKAction.repeatForever(moveLeft)
        player.run(SKAction.group([moveLeftForEver, leftForever]), withKey: "moveLeft")
    } else {
       playerWalk = SKAction.animate(with: textures,timePerFrame: 0.1)
        let rightForever = SKAction.repeatForever(playerWalk)
        let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 60, y: 0, duration: 0.2)
        let moveRightForEver = SKAction.repeatForever(moveRight)
        player.run(SKAction.group([moveRightForEver, rightForever]), withKey: "moveRight")
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: actually, I read your code wrong first comment...  I think you might experiment with the time per frame and the distance in your move action to see if you can make it look more like walking instead of sliding.

Comment: I don't know how can I do better? Actually I didn't like this way...

Comment: "Better" is subjective.

Comment: @JohnD. textures represent a movement in space (as I understand, a step?), so you need to synchronize that texture animation with the corresponding position on screen. You have 10 textures animated at 1/10s so it takes 1 sec for a step, but the corresponding screen move is 60 pixels in 0.2 seconds. Does this corresponds? Probably not. At least duration of move should equals to total duration of animation. Something like that.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thank you for your advise. I fixed it.